# How to unescape JSON/Java with support to ampersand?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, escaping, stringescapeutils

### Background

I need to parse some string from HTML that is of a URL (seems it's inside JSON), so I tried to use org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson.

An example of such a URL started with this as the input:

```
https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/v\/t51.2885-19\/40405422_462181764265305_1222152915674726400_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150\\u0026
```

### The problem

It seems it had some characters that weren't handled so if I perform this:

```
val test="https:\\/\\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\\/v\\/t51.2885-19\\/40405422_462181764265305_1222152915674726400_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150\\\\u0026\n"
Log.d("AppLog", "${StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(test)}")
```

the result is:

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/40405422_462181764265305_1222152915674726400_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150\u0026
```

You can see that there is still "0026" in it, so I've found that using this solved it:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(input).replace("\\u0026","&").replace("\\/", "/")
```

This works, but I think I should use something more official, as it might fail due to too-direct replacing of substrings.

### What I've tried

Looking at unescapeJson code (which is the same for Java&Json, it seems), I thought that maybe I could just add the rules:

```
/**based on StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson, but with addition of 2 more rules*/
fun unescapeUrl(input: String): String {
    val unescapeJavaMap= hashMapOf<CharSequence, CharSequence>(
        "\\\\" to "\\",
        "\\\\" to "\\",
        "\\\"" to "\"",
        "\\'" to "'",
        "\\" to StringUtils.EMPTY,
        //added rules:
        "\\u0026" to "&",
        "\\/" to "/"
    )
    val aggregateTranslator = AggregateTranslator(
        OctalUnescaper(),
        UnicodeUnescaper(),
        LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.JAVA_CTRL_CHARS_UNESCAPE),
        LookupTranslator(Collections.unmodifiableMap(unescapeJavaMap))
    )
    return aggregateTranslator.translate(input)
}
```

This doesn't work. It leaves the string with "\u0026" in it.

### The questions

1. What did I do wrong here? How can I fix this?
2. It is true it's best to use something similar to the original code, instead of using "replace", right?

BTW, I use this on Android using Kotlin, but same can be done on Java on PC.

Comment: It is not clear what is your original HTML with JSON. Example would help.

Comment: @P_M it's just an escaped URL. No need to post entire HTML. I've added an example of its beginning

Answer (score 0):

Let me just give you my working example using `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(input)` without `replace`. I've also looked into the `StringEscapeUtils` source code, which might help you a bit.

**Here is my working Kotlin code** (Java works the same in my test).

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val input = "Hello ampersand \\u0026 and forward slash \\/"
    println(input)

    val output1 = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(input)
    println(output1)

    val output2 = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(input).replace("\\u0026", "&").replace("\\/", "/")
    println(output2)
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello ampersand \u0026 and forward slash \/ - original input
Hello ampersand & and forward slash /       - StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(input)
Hello ampersand & and forward slash /       - StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(input).replace...
```

As you can see, the outputs are identical regardless of using the `replace` logic. I'm using `org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.10.0`.

If we look into their source code, it's could be clear that we don't have to add any `replace("\\u0026", "&").replace("\\/", "/")` because:

- the escaped-unicode representation of ampersand is handled by [UnicodeUnescaper](https://github.com/apache/commons-text/blob/b83474667d6f8ede75d6a0c4289e01bc2a54bae9/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/text/translate/UnicodeUnescaper.java#L29). You can see it being used in your `unescapeUrl` originally replicated from [UNESCAPE_JAVA](https://github.com/apache/commons-text/blob/b83474667d6f8ede75d6a0c4289e01bc2a54bae9/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.java#L395) implementation.
- the `\\/` string is handled by another existing rule at [UNESCAPE_JAVA](https://github.com/apache/commons-text/blob/b83474667d6f8ede75d6a0c4289e01bc2a54bae9/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.java#L392), which is `unescapeJavaMap.put("\\", StringUtils.EMPTY)` and also replicated in your `unescapeUrl`.

**So, answering your questions *(NB: also see the UPDATE below taking into account the "broken" input from the author, which was posted later)*:**

1. Not obvious what is wrong in your example using just `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(input)` as you can see, it works in my Kotlin example (Java as well). Maybe the version of the "common-text" library? But I doubt that. I'm also using PC, not Android. *See the **UPDATE** below explaining the "broken" input posted later by the author and how to deal with that.*
2. It is true, totally agree. And in this particular example, not even "something similar". You should be fine using the out-of-the-box method. No need to customise that in either way.

I hope, this answer helps. Also, as it was mentioned in the comments, a good example from you would be very helpful!

**UPDATE:**
Looking into the author's example (posted later), I can see that the escaped-unicode representation of ampersand is sort of double-escaped in the input as `\\u0026` instead of `\u0026`. Thus, the problem. If you look into the source code of that [UNESCAPE_JAVA (UNESCAPE_JSON)](https://github.com/apache/commons-text/blob/b83474667d6f8ede75d6a0c4289e01bc2a54bae9/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.java#L389), you will see that the `\\` string get transformed into a single backslash `\` as in `unescapeJavaMap.put("\\\\", "\\")`, and then in [that translators iteration](https://github.com/apache/commons-text/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/text/translate/AggregateTranslator.java#L60) the index advances **by 2** as two characters have been replaced, which places the index at the `u` character.

I would say, this is the upstream problem that sends you a badly formatted string. **Ideally**, it should be fixed so that they don't double escape the characters represented in escaped-unicode format. Then `\\u0026` should become `\u0026`.

You can also compose your own `AggregateTranslator` the way it properly handles this scenario. There might be few options but they could all be error-prone and stop working properly in other scenarios. So, you have to be careful with that.

You can also run the `unescapeJson` method twice and it works in your particular example as in `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(input))`. But obviously, you could easily over-unescape the input.

Comment: You want me to remove the "replace", but as I wrote, this means the characters stayed, and so if I try to open a URL (such as a URL to an image) it would fail. I can't let those characters stay in the URL. I've added an example of its beginning inside my post.

Comment: @androiddeveloper you can check out my detailed update in the answer.

Comment: As I wrote, it doesn't work without the "replace". I had to add it. I've updated my question again, showing what happens when I don't use "replace".

Comment: @androiddeveloper right, like I said, you can check out my answer and all the links I've posted. Then, you can easily use either of the suggested options that perfectly work on your example. But like I said, you have to be careful with that and all of them make some assumptions about the input. So does your "replace" approach. Ideally, the input must not be that "broken" as I've explained in my answer.

Comment: I'm not responsible about the input, and I don't understand what you are offering. Sorry